# Attempting to send a parameter through GET only sends part

Tags: php, url, get

I'm trying to send a parameter via GET.

This is my url:

```
http://localhost/app_yy/public/hotel/cancel?AvailSply=ID_B2B_20#RA1B2BHB
```

This is the result of the `print_r` function:

```
Array
(
    [AvailSply] => ID_B2B_20
)
```

However, I was expected `AvailSply` to be `ID_B2B_20#RA1B2BHB` -- why is part of it cut off?

Comment: @AmitRajput While that tangentially relates to the question, it doesn't provide even a sarcastic answer, since it requires knowing the solution to see how it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

> Why is part of it cut off?

Because the parameter contains a `#`. If you have a pound in your URL, it won't be treated as part of a GET parameter, but the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). See how the part that's there is the same as the part in front of the `#`? That's because the browser is assuming anything after it is a

That syntax -- "anything after the `#` identifies a fragment" -- means that you can't include that character in a GET parameter.

#### The solution

You can [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it, though, which means your URL will look like

```
http://localhost/app_yy/public/hotel/cancel?AvailSply=ID_B2B_20%23RA1B2BHB
```

rather than what you have. Note the `%23` instead of `#` -- that, when decoded, turns into a `#`, but doesn't trigger the fragment identifier parsing.

There are plenty of libraries to URL-encode stuff -- in PHP, for example, you can use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) and [`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode).

---

<sup>The Wikipedia article has a good description of what a fragment identifier is, but in layman's English, the fragment identifier marks where in the page you wanna go. It's useful if you want to, say, link to subheadings in a document, or tabs within a page. However, here, it's not what you want.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In an URL, with the number sign (#) hashes, or links to ancors, are tagged.
If you wish to transmit # as a GET parameter value you have to escape it:

- In Javascript:

  > escape(value)
- Manually (%23 stands for #):

  > ....?AvailSply=ID_B2B_20%23RA1B2BHB